# Easily Mirror Client sites

Tags: backup, server, mirror

I need to figure out how to easily mirror a client's site, but the mirror needs to sync if the client makes changes on the site.

an example is http://www.nailcotehall.co.uk mirrored here http://nailcotehall-px.rtrk.co.uk/index.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=NailcoteLandingPage

Comment: Which operating systems you are using?

Comment: Our server aren't completely setup yet, so that gives us complete flexibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have linux/unix servers and have `SSH` access for both of them you can use rsync to sync modified files/directories from one server to another.
For example:

```
rsync -a ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

See: http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/

This can be make periodic with `cron`

Comment: So was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I expect so. Thanks. Was hoping for a Windows based option as well. But its probably a given we are going with a linux/unix based infrustructure

Comment: Happy to help. I would also prefer unix for almost everything ;). But have to say that you can do similar syncin on window with robocopy http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy